# Pentaho: Loop through start date to end date

Tags: loops, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

Within Pentaho's PDI, I am trying to go day by day from a start date until the current date. I am trying to pass this date to a Rest Client. So for example, I start 5 days ago, pass that date to the Rest client task, then go to 4 days ago, pass that date to the Rest client task, then go to 3 days ago, pass that date to the Rest client task, etc... until the current date. How do I accomplish this type of loop using PDI? Really appreciate any help or insight anyone can lend here.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @jxc! I think this is exactly what I want but is there a tutorial vid or project out there that you know of with this to help me walk through this?

Comment: the input is a start_date. thanks.

Comment: Hello @jxc, apologies on my delay but I was planning to add feedback (and MORE than happy to do so) but seems like you removed the answer/help? Or am I missing something? Thank you so much for your time and help here!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the `start_date` is a parameter which you set up through the main menu `Edit` -> `settings` -> `Parameters` tab with the following entry:

```
Parameter: start_date
Default Value: 2020-09-10
```

then you can try the following transformation with 4 steps:

[image]

**Step-1:** `Get System Info` Step, add one field with Name=`today` and Type=`Today 00:00:00`

**Step-2:** `Calculator` Step, set up the following 3 fields:
[image]

1. `_start_date`: Set field to constant value A
2. `start_date`: variable substitution in string A
3. `n_repeat`: Data A - DataB(in days)

**Step-3:** `Clone row` Step, do the following:

[image]

- Check `Nr clone in field?` and set the field name to `n_repeat`
- Check `Add clone num to` and set the field name to `rn`

**Step-4:** `Calculator` Step, add three fields:
[image]

1. `new_date`: Date A + B Days
2. `base_uri`: Set field to constant value A
3. `request_uri`: A + B

Run the above transformation with start_date = '2020-09-10', we have the output:
[image]

**Note:** you can add one more `Select values` Step to keep only desired fields.